# chrome or express or react not allowing cookie to be set in browser

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies

apologies in advance for what seems like a repeat question.

I've tried lots of other stack overflow and other solutions and cant seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to send and set a cookie from my express server to my front end so that it can be sent back with each request to authenticate.
This is working in insomnia and on the 9090 host but when I push it up to the proper server it just stops working and wont set the cookie at all.

all the headers are showing up

I'm also getting no errors in the console so no help there.

react example of request

```
    export const logIn = (formInput) => {
      return listApi.post(`/users/authenticate`, formInput, {withCredentials:true})
      .then( ({ data }) => {
        return data
      })
```

express

```
        app.use(cors({
        origin: "http://192.xxx.x.xx:xxxx",
        credentials: true,
        origin: true
    }));
```

```
       res.status(200)
        .header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
        .header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.1.69:3000")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS")
        .cookie('access_token', token, {expires:tokenExpire, 
          sameSite: 'None', 
          secure: true, 
          httpOnly: true, 
          Domain: 'http://192.168.1.69:3000'})
        .send({ msg: 'success' });
      } else {
        Promise.reject( {status: 401, msg: 'unauthorized - invalid username and password'})
        .catch(err => next(err))
      }
    };
```

EDIT:
here are the things I've read so far

[res.cookie not setting cookie in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787770/res-cookie-not-setting-cookie-in-browser)

[Express-Session not working in production/deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65767024/express-session-not-working-in-production-deployment/65767783#65767783)

[Express-session cookie not saving in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72254943/express-session-cookie-not-saving-in-browser)

[Cookies on localhost with explicit domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134290/cookies-on-localhost-with-explicit-domain/1188145#1188145)

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/vxvdib/cookie_not_being_set_in_react_app_express_backend/

[Express doesn't set a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36824106/express-doesnt-set-a-cookie)

Comment: Your cookie's `Domain` attribute is invalid. Leave it out altogether.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for your response. I've now removed that and it still doesn't want to set the cookie...

Comment: What is the URL of your server? Does it use `http` or `https`? If it uses `http`, it cannot set a `Secure` cookie.

Comment: it seems to be a https URL.

Comment: found something that's worked for me (I think).  

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523383/express-not-setting-cookie][1]

"...the cookie should be set on the API server domain, NOT on client domain".

If anyone has a more in depth explanation to why this works I'd be happy to have a read! Right now I'm a bit dubious as I don't see how without the cookie being exchanged its actually secure and unfortunately don't have enough rep to add a comment to the original post...

[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523383/express-not-setting-cookie